# Android Spinner's random item id not getting properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter, android-volley, android-spinner

I have a android spinner like this

[image]

First one is item name and second one is their respective item id.**I want to send respective item id to server when item name is selected** and I don't want to desplay item id also.How to resolve this here is my code:

```
public class Form extends BaseActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://url/Service.asmx/GenerateTicket";

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    public static final String CUSTOMERID = "customerId";
    public static final String USERNAME = "name";
    public static final String HOUSENO = "houseNo";
    public static final String LOCALITY = "areaName";
    public static final String SERVICE = "serviceId";
    public static final String MOBILE = "mobile";
    public static final String EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String PROBLEM = "jobBrief";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
Spinner spin;
    // flag for Internet connection status
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

    // Connection detector class
    ConnectionDetector cd;

//    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
//    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private List<Item> customerList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private SpinAdapter adapter;
    private List<Item> items;

    private EditText editname, houseNo, mobile, email, problem;
    Spinner service_need;
    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView;
    String obj;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_form, frameLayout);
        autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.colony);

        autoCompView.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));
        autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        editname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        houseNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.houseNo);
//   
        mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        problem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.problem);
        Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        // get Internet status
        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
//      


        assert submit != null;
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (editname.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else if (houseNo.toString().trim().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Form.this, "Please enter your house no", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (autoCompView.toString().trim().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Form.this, "Please enter your locality", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

//                } else if (service_need.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("Select Service")) {
//                    Toast.makeText(Form.this, "Please Select item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
//                }
                else if (mobile.toString().trim().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Form.this, "Please enter your mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else if (mobile.getText().length() < 10) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter valid mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }

                else if (problem.toString().trim().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Form.this, "Please describe your problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else if (!email.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
                {
                    if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(
                            email.getText().toString().trim()).matches()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Please enter valid e-mail id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                    else {
                        if (isInternetPresent) {
                            registerUser();
                            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                            pDialog.show();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "connecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();



                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(Form.this, "Unable to connect the server, please check your data settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                }

                else {
                    // Do your stuff


                    if (isInternetPresent) {
                        registerUser();
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                        pDialog.show();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "connecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }

                    else {

                        Toast.makeText(Form.this, "Unable to connect the server, please check your data settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }

                }

            }


        });
//   

        spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.service_need);
        adapter = new SpinAdapter(this, customerList);
        spin.setAdapter(adapter);




    }

    private void registerUser() {

        final SharedPreferences mSharedPreference= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        final String value=(mSharedPreference.getString("customerId", "Default_Value"));



        final String customer_id = value.trim();
        final String username = editname.getText().toString().trim();
        final String house = houseNo.getText().toString().trim();
        final String local_area = autoCompView.getText().toString().trim();


         **Something wrong with this line**
        **final String service = spin.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();**


        final String mobile_no = mobile.getText().toString().trim();
        final String email_id = email.getText().toString().trim();
        final String prob = problem.getText().toString().trim();

        Toast.makeText(Form.this, username.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(Form.this, service.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(Form.this, local_area.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {


                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        hidePDialog();
                        try {
                            //String result="";
                            //Do it with this it will work
                            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject person = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String excep = person.getString("Exception");
                                String message1 = person.getString("Message");
                                String job = person.getString("JobNo");

                                if (excep.equalsIgnoreCase("True")) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Form.this, excep, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .show();
                                } else {

                                    Toast.makeText(Form.this, excep, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .show();
                                    editname.setText("");
                                    // if email and mb is valid than login

                                    Intent i1 = new Intent(Form.this, Suceessful.class);
                                    i1.putExtra("job_id", job);
                                    startActivity(i1);
                                    finish();
                                    Toast.makeText(Form.this, excep.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Toast.makeText(Form.this, message1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Toast.makeText(Form.this, job.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(Form.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(CUSTOMERID,customer_id);
                params.put(USERNAME, username);
                params.put(HOUSENO, house);
                params.put(LOCALITY, local_area);
                params.put(SERVICE, service);
                params.put(MOBILE, mobile_no);
                params.put(EMAIL, email_id);
                params.put(PROBLEM, prob);
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }





        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            InputStream is = null;
            String result = "";
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://url/Service.asmx/GetServiceList");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                // Get our response as a String.
                is = entity.getContent();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //convert response to string
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                is.close();
                //result=sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // parse json data
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Item customer = new Item();
                    customer.setiD(obj.getString("ServiceId"));
                    customer.setsText(obj.getString("ServiceName"));

                    // adding movie to movies array
                    customerList.add(customer);


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
//            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            customerList.addAll(items);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
//         Inflate menu to add items to action bar if it is present.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.refresh);
        item.setVisible(false);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: instead `ArrayAdapter<String>` use `ArrayAdapter<MyClass>` where `MyClass` keeps both service name and service id

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to achieve this. I think the simplest way is to create a model class for your spinner item.

```
public class Item implements Serializable {
    public String sText;
    public int iD;

    public int getiD() {
        return iD;
    }

    public void setiD(int iD) {
        this.iD = iD;
    }

    public Item(String sText, int iD) {
        this.sText = sText;
        this.iD=iD;
    }

    public String getsText() {
        return sText;
    }

    public void setsText(String sText) {
        this.sText = sText;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Item item = (Item) o;
        if (item.getiD()==iD)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.sText;            // What to display in the Spinner list.
    }
}
```

In the activity class you can create an `ArrayAdapter`.

```
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
private List<Item> items;
```

Inside `onCreate` initialize list and adapter and set the adapter.

```
items= new ArrayList<>();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
service_need.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Replace json parsing like this:

```
// parse json data
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // add interviewee name to arraylist
                    items.add(new Item(jsonObject.getString("ServiceName"),jsonObject.getString("ServiceId")));

                    }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` inside `onPostExecute()`.

In the `onClick`, you can fetch the customer ID from the spinner.

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
String customer_id=customerList.get(spinner_cat.getSelectedItemPosition()).getiD();
```

Comment: could you update the code you used and post the error log.

Comment: Plz see my updated code. now it populateld proprly but did not excute onresponse function of register user function (may be due to not not get proper id)

Comment: if any query about code plz ask me.. I have tried a lot but nothing happen.

Comment: Why aren't you using the selected customer id from the spinner?

Comment: It's not reading anything still anything,I'm too tired to work on this but nothing happen

Answer (score 1):

To hide the Id you must not add it to the array you are passing to spinner.

Use a structure to create objects with properties name and id.

```
private static class Items
{
    public String name;
    public String id;
}
```

You can add setters and getters methods.
Create a list of Items object. Set each object values for name and id from server.
Create an array of strings for spinner consisting of names of Items objects in order.
On selection event of spinner, get the id of Items object in the list from selected position and use it to send to server.